# google play Application is rejected reason is vulnerabilities intent redirection

Tags: android, google-play

When I upload my application I got notification for vulnerabilities intent redirection from google play store My application is rejected three times because of these reason I did `exported="false"` in every activity

Answer (score 0):

It is important that your app does not call startActivity, startService, sendBroadcast, or setResult on untrusted Intents without validating or sanitizing these Intents.

[Solution for Intent Redirection Vulnerability](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en)